# how to use nokogiri to parse xml file for specific values?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an xml file from which I need to extract all values that contain `https://www.example.com/a/b`:

```
<xml>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/a/b</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/b/c</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/a/b/c</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/c/d</loc></url>
</xml>
```

Given the above, this should return two results. I've opened the file and parsed it with Nokogiri, but I do not understand how to access the values of the `//loc` key.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = File.open('./sitemap-en.xml') { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
puts doc.xpath('//loc')
```

The above code puts the entire xml file, but I want it paired down so that I get everything under the `/a/b` subdirectories. How can I do this?

Comment: Content of XML nodes doesn't have any semantic meaning from the XML point of view, so Nokogiri has nothing to do with that.  In other words,  you can use Nokogiri to extract the urls from this XML, but any processing of the urls themselves is an absolutely separate problem...

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following solutions assume the following:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-XML
<xml>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/a/b</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/b/c</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/a/b/c</loc></url>
 <url><loc>https://www.example.com/c/d</loc></url>
</xml>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

To return a list of all `loc` elements, `select` only those whose inner text begins with `https://www.example.com/a/b`, and print the URL text:

```rb
elements = doc.xpath("//loc")

filtered_elements = elements.select do |element|
  element.text.start_with? 'https://www.example.com/a/b'
end

filtered_elements.each do |element|
  puts element.text
end
```

To capture a list of `loc` elements whose inner text contains the string `https://www.example.com/a/b` and print each URL:

```rb
elements = doc.xpath("//loc[contains(text(), 'https://www.example.com/a/b')]")

elements.each do |element|
  puts element.text
end
```

To quickly print URLs using a slightly modified version of the previous XPATH query

```rb
puts doc.xpath("//loc[contains(text(), 'https://www.example.com/a/b')]/text()")
```